# Ruby 2.6: How can I dynamically override instance methods when prepending a module?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a module called `Notifier`.

```
module Notifier
  def self.prepended(host_class)
    host_class.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def emit_after(*methods)
      methods.each do |method|
        define_method(method) do |thing, block|
          r = super(thing)
          block.call
          r
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It exposes a class method `emit_after`. I use it like so:

```
class Player
  prepend Notifier
  attr_reader :inventory

  emit_after :take

  def take(thing)
    # ...
  end
end
```

The intention is that by calling `emit_after :take`, the module overrides `#take` with its own method.

But the instance method isn't being overridden.

I *can* however, override it explicitly without using `ClassMethods`

```
module Notifier
  def self.prepended(host_class)
    define_method(:take) do |thing, block|
      r = super(thing)
      block.call
      r
    end
  end

class Player
  prepend Notifier
  attr_reader :inventory

  def take(thing)
    # ...
  end
end

#> @player.take @apple, -> { puts "Taking apple" }
#Taking apple
#=> #<Inventory:0x00007fe35f608a98...
```

I know that `ClassMethods#emit_after` is called so I assume that the method is being defined but it just never gets called.

I want to create the methods dynamically. How can I ensure that the generate method overrides my instance method?

Answer (score 6):

`@Konstantin Strukov`'s solution is good but maybe a little confusing. So, I suggest another solution, which is more like the original one.

Your first goal is to add a **class method** (`emit_after`) to your class. To do that you should use `extend` method without any hooks such as `self.prepended()`, `self.included()` or `self.extended()`.

`prepend`, as well as `include`, are used to add or override **instance methods**. But that is your second goal and it happens when you call `emit_after`. So you shouldn't use `prepend` or `include` when extending your class.

```
module Notifier
  def emit_after(*methods)
    prepend(Module.new do
      methods.each do |method|
        define_method(method) do |thing, &block|
          super(thing)
          block.call if block
        end
      end
    end)
  end
end

class Player
  extend Notifier

  emit_after :take

  def take(thing)
    puts thing
  end
end

Player.new.take("foo") { puts "bar" }  
# foo
# bar
# => nil
```

Now it is obvious that you call `extend Notifier` in order to add the `emit_after` class method and all the magic is hidden in the method.

Comment: I've just tried this in pry but it doesn't look like the method is being overridden.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that you've used `&` before the block argument so that you don't have to use shabby lambda.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It is exactly what I was looking for ! I wasn't confident because of the comments but it definitely works ! (in Rails 4 at least)

Answer (score 3):

What about this solution:

```rb
module Notifier
  def self.[](*methods)
    Module.new do
      methods.each do |method|
        define_method(method) do |thing, &block|
          super(thing)
          block.call if block
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class Player
  prepend Notifier[:take]

  def take(thing)
    puts "I'm explicitly defined"
  end
end

Player.new.take(:foo) { puts "I'm magically prepended" }
# => I'm explicitly defined
# => I'm magically prepended
```

It's quite similar to the solution from Aleksei Matiushkin, but the ancestors' chain is a bit cleaner (no "useless" Notifier there)

Comment: This is how I would do this in the real life, yes.

Comment: _"no "useless" Notifier there"_ – maybe `prepend Notifier[:take]` is a bit misleading in that regard. It looks as if you are prepending `Notifier`, whereas you actually prepend the anonymous module returned by `[]`. Your `Notifier` is actually just a container for the `[]` method, nothing more, nothing less. It doesn't appear in `Player`'s ancestors chain.

Comment: @Stefan indeed. I should stop trying to give answers on Ruby, I seem to forget the language basics :)

Comment: @Stefan "maybe prepend Notifier[:take] is a bit misleading in that regard". Is it really? Imo this trick may be misleading only when you see it for the first time, but in general, it's more straightforward and predictable (in terms of resulting ancestors' chain) than playing with hooks.

Comment: _"Imo"_ ← lol, I read "lmao" :-) With _misleading_ I just mean that it looks as if you are prepending (some kind of) `Notifier`, but instead an unrelated anonymous module is prepended. I would expect `prepend Notifier[:take]` to result in `Player.ancestors` containing (some kind of) `Notifier`, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Prepend to the currently opened class:

```
module Notifier
  def self.prepended(host_class)
    host_class.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def emit_after(*methods)
    # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ HERE  
      prepend(Module.new do
        methods.each do |method|
          define_method(method) do |thing, block = nil|
            super(thing).tap { block.() if block }
          end
        end
      end)
    end
  end
end

class Player
  prepend Notifier
  attr_reader :inventory

  emit_after :take

  def take(thing)
    puts "foo"
  end
end

Player.new.take :foo, -> { puts "Taking apple" }
#⇒ foo
#  Taking apple
```

Comment: It might be misleading that `Notifier` is still prepended. You could also use the more common `include Notifier` (along with `self.included`). It might also make sense to have a single anonymous module for overriding methods instead of creating a new module for each `emit_after` call.

Comment: @Stefan accumulating methods to pack them into the single module would require [`TracePoint#new(:end)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/TracePoint.html#method-c-new) and thus will be overcomplicating the answer. I tried to apply as few modifications to the original code as possible.

Comment: You just have to remember the anonymous module you are prepending and send `define_method` to that module.

Comment: @Stefan Oh, adding methods to the _already_ prepended module has an effect on the prepending target as well; thanks, I didn’t know.

Comment: Yes, if you define the methods directly on the prepended module. Including other modules into the prepended module on the other hand would not work, i.e. you can add methods, but you can't alter the ancestor chain afterwards.

Comment: @Stefan “you can't alter the ancestor chain afterwards”—that I knew and that’s exactly why I mistakenly supposed it does not work with an explicit method definitions either.